# Using spacy visualizer with custom data

Tags: data-visualization, customization, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to visualize a sentence using Spacy's named entity visualizer. I have a sentence with some user defined labels over the tokens, and I want to visualize them using the NER rendering API.

I don't want to train and produce a predictive model, I have all needed labels from an external source, just need the visualization without messing too much with front-end libraries.

Any ideas how?
Thank you

Comment: You could create your own custom matcher and add it as a step into the pipeline of ``nlp()``

Answer (score 2):

You can manually modify the list of entities (`doc.ents`) and add new spans using token offsets. Be aware that entities can't overlap at all.

```py
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Span
nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['ner'])
doc = nlp("I see an XYZ.")
doc.ents = list(doc.ents) + [Span(doc, 3, 4, "NEWENTITYTYPE")]
print(doc.ents[0], doc.ents[0].label_)
```

Output:

```py
XYZ NEWENTITYTYPE
```